# When is it okay to use weasel words?

Tags: vocabulary

When is it okay to use 'weasel words', like may, might, could, perhaps, possibly, potentially etc.?

Is it at all acceptable to use them in an essay, e.g. a History essay?

Comment: I think the real question is exactly how you're using them in the history essay.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer to this. The only real answer is "you can get away with it when you can get away with it" (which should also demonstrate the problem with weasel words). I think a better approach is to pause, reflect, and ask yourself "why do I want to include these words?". What is your motivation? If it's something like "Well, I can't find any sources to support it..", then back up one step and say "so what makes me believe it enough to include it?". You say "well, it makes logical sense"... and the light begins to break. *Can* you make a logical argument?  Etc etc.

Comment: @PeterShor An example of this would be: "This factor may have caused the leader to introduce the policy."

Comment: @user313272 Great, so back up a step. Why do you believe the factor may have caused the leader to.... . Is it because he mentioned it in a speech about the policy? Is it because his party has a history of supporting the policy? Is it because it would benefit him personally? Did a respected journalist suggest it in an article about the policy? AKA, can you turn the speculation into an *argument*?

Comment: @DanBron I use them because in my essay, I am trying to figure out why a leader launched a specific policy, and it's not really possible to say that "this factor **definitely** caused the leader to launch the policy". Would this be an acceptable use of weasel words?

Comment: What you call "weasel words" **might** look to others as prudent recognition that some things that look like facts **may** merely represent probabilities.

Comment: I'd like you to answer the question I asked in my previous comment (and alluded to in the first). Why *this factor* and not *that factor* or *the price of tea in China*? Everyone understands you can't prove intent, but to the extent you can *make an argument this particular factor was likely to influence the politician*, it strengthens your essay, and raises a defense against charges of weasel-wording. And you'll get better marks from your prof, because this is what he's looking for. Don't just *say* this factor could be an influence, *tell us why*.

Comment: I'm not sure this is [on topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this stack. In any case, as it is this is about writing style, you might get a better answer at [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm flagging this as too broad/POB, since as it's currently worded it's hard to see how there could be a definitive answer and instead it's likely to invite a range of personal views. **I support @tmgr's suggestion that migrating it to [writing.se] might be appropriate**, though even there it may be too broad - I'd recommend narrowing the scope to some specific examples that test what might be suitable or unsuitable.

Answer (score 2):

The term "weasel words" is a pejorative put in place by rhetoricians that see words like "probably" or "potentially" as conveying a lack of conviction in the writer's argument or ideas. In the realm of statistical data and empiricism, however, they serve a vital purpose in managing expectations and accurately representing uncertainty around certain results and findings.

It is worth pointing out that in the sciences (hard and social) the use of these words is always accompanied by evidence to back up the assertion, they are not used in lieu of evidence. If you say something is "probably true", you'd best have some verifiable facts to back up that claim. This is equally the case in a history paper as in the documentation for a physics experiment.

If accuracy of objective information is important, then weasel away. If you're trying to convey your personal thoughts, then stick to strong, confident verbiage.